# Static member initialization and variadic template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, static-members, static-initialization

By looking at the following code, we note that it's quite easy to initialize the static data member named `cnt`:

```
template<typename T> struct Base { static int cnt; };
template<typename T> int Base<T>::cnt = 0;
int main() { }
```

Anyway, I'm struggling with `variadic_template` and static data members, for I'm not able to make it with them. Consider the following code:

```
template<typename...> struct Base;
template<> struct Base<> { static int cnt; };
int main() { }
```

First of all, I tried the most obvious thing, at least the one that was the most obvious to me:

```
template<typename... T> int Base<T...>::cnt = 0;
```

It returned `error: template definition of non-template ‘int Base<T>::cnt’` and I immediately realized that my attempt didn't make sense indeed. That said, I was a bit puzzled after that, because it was no longer obvious to me which was the right syntax.

I tried the following ones:

```
template<> int Base<>::cnt = 0;
// ... and ...
template<> int Base::cnt = 0;
```

With the errors `error: template definition of non-template ‘unsigned int Base<T>::cnt’` and `error: ‘template<class ... T> struct Base’ used without template parameters`.

So far, I've worked a little with `variadic template`s and I've no idea about how to make it with them. I cannot even figure out neither if it's possible nor which the correct syntax is.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use just

```
int Base<>::cnt = 42;
```

At this point, `Base<>` is a full specialization, you don't specialize anything, so `template<>` is not necessary anymore, being actually forbidden.

Comment: @skypjack Nothing to be ashamed of ;) The template syntax is one of the most dark parts of C++.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you, but that was quite obvious!! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Just initialize it as:

`int Base<>::cnt = 0;`

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b54c93eecefad5b)